# Is there a way to handle a message for a MassTransit Saga state machine without having to encapsulate it in an envelope using HandleSaga?

Tags: masstransit, saga

I want to handle a message I receive on a service bus using:
_receiver.HandleSaga(MyQueue, message, cancellationToken)

But I receive following error: "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'envelope')"

I created a SagaDefinition class like so

```
public class MySagaDefinition : SagaDefinition<MyState>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureSaga(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, ISagaConfigurator<MyState> sagaConfigurator, IRegistrationContext context)
        {
            if (endpointConfigurator is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
            {
                sb.RequiresSession = true;
                sb.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                sb.DefaultContentType = new ContentType("application/json");
                sb.ClearSerialization();
                sb.UseRawJsonSerializer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Yet the error still occurs

I also use 'AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions' which does not contain UseRawJsonSerializer() in it's configuration for some reason...

Does anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the raw JSON serializer on the bus configuration.

```cs
services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumerNamespace>();
    },
    
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus",
    (_,cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer();
    });
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the quick reply. initially it did not work but after adding the AddMassTransitEventHub it did the job. Are there extra setting involving this message envelope in there? Just out of curiosity :)

Comment: The event hub should only be required if you're using event hub.